# Different noise when knock on a hollow wall

Tags: acoustics

This might have a very simple answer, but I was wondering whether there was more to it.

When we knock on a wall, the noise is different depending on whether there's a hollow space behind it or not.

Why?

Does this depend on the fact that sound propagates differently through the wall and then through the air behind?

Comment: hi see this http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/174440/why-do-thuds-occur yes is the answer  to your last line, imo  regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The musical property of a guitar, a violin, a cello, and indeed any string instrument, depend to a great extent on the shape of the empty space they contain.  Such property also depends on the vibrational properties of the wood that encloses their empty space.  Empty space properly enclosed within a thin skin is like an echo chamber that can magnify vibrations.

But when you knock on a solid wall, the empty space on the other side may be an entire roomful of emptiness, which tends to dissipate rather than to concentrate sound, and the wall itself has minimal vibrational properties because it is thicker and has more mass per square inch of surface area than the surface of a hollow wall.

Sound-proofing a room often involves painting the walls with mass-loaded vinyl, or gluing mass-loaded vinyl sheeting to the surface.  The more massive a surface, the more energy is required to create a vibration.   Also, the more mass loaded on a surface, the more surface area is required for sound waves to propagate.  For example, one may strike a 1 foot thick by 1 foot square block of steel and elicit only a dull clank.  But if the steel is 1 foot thick and 1,000 feet square, a suitably energetic blow will elicit impressive vibrations.  If A solid wall comprises a large enough surface in relation to its mass, and if the blow is suitably energetic, even such a wall might vibrate enough to create music (of a sort).

So, there are at least two reasons a solid wall sounds different from a hollow wall:  (1) More mass per surface area, and (2) more diffuse space which makes it more difficult to reflect and concentrate sound waves.